# Select Query[SQL or Access SQL]- if value is x, do not return n records matching timestamp of record x

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have a activity log table that contains too many excess records. Each record has a description, time processed, Date processed, user.

I would like to create a query selecting records where if the description is like "new account" then do not return 2 records that matches the "new account" record's time, date, and user.

Is such a thing possible?

Each time a new account is made, additional entries are automatically generated, which I would like to omit.

i.e.
Desired result:
1:30PM, Feb 28 2017, David, New Account

1:30PM, Feb 28 2017, David, Testing

Undesired result:

1:30PM, Feb 28 2017, David, New Account

1:30PM, Feb 28 2017, David, address added

1:30PM, Feb 28 2017, David, status updated

1:30PM, Feb 28 2017, David, Testing

The example drops two records that matches time,date and user where "new account" occurs. The dropped records can be before "new account" or after, it's not too important

Comment: Could you reword your question? I've read it 4 times and cannot make any sense of what you are asking. The "do not return 2 records" part is not making sense to me.

Comment: edited the main post with an example

Comment: can you not just put in your where clause WHERE description<>'address added' AND description<>'status updated' ? or am I still not understanding?

Comment: description could house hundreds of different strings, it's not important what gets dropped specifically, just that 2 records must be dropped for every new account

Comment: and you dont care which 2 records?

Comment: i dont care which 2 records, as long as they share the same time, date, and user as the record showing "new account"

Comment: is there always a consistent number of records returned? if so, you could use a SELECT TOP 10 query.

Comment: is your where clause already filtering the dataset down by date, time, name? or are you selecting multiple occurrences of your keys and just want to remove 2 of however many there are for each key? IT may have been a good idea to include your exact SELECT statement to clarify.

Comment: There is no select statement yet, I am working with the entire table and (millions of records) with many dates, times, users and descriptions. I need to sift through them for "new account", then remove 2 similar records with the same time, date, and user

Comment: You are probably going to need some VBA code to do that then.

Comment: If `New Account` will always be one of the descriptions in each record grouping you can do this with some clever grouping.

Comment: @SunKnight0 can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: If you use something like this: `GROUP BY Date, Time, User, Description='New Account'` you will get two records, one with the 'New Account' description and one other. Using `FIRST(Description)` in your `SELECT` statement for example will give you the first other description.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work (continued from my comment).

```
SELECT [Date], [Time], User, FIRST(Description) as MyDescription
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Date, Time, User, Description='New Account'
```

Comment: If the new account it manually typed you may have typos and extra spaces. You will have to change the expression to use something like this: `Description LIKE '*New*Account*'`

Comment: On further testing, the results set will return records with the same date, time, and user. It seems to only drop the right records if those records come AFTER a "new account" entry. It'll also keep the first record for a given date/time/user as long as it is the first, so if a "new account" happens for the same user and time, the new account record gets dropped. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: For each date/time/user combo it will keep the first record that matches `'*New*Account*'` or whatever criteria you are using and the first record that does not match that criteria. Whether the non-New Account records come before or after should not matter. If you are getting anything different you need to tweak the separation criteria.